# file upload won't upload .Json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, mongodb, gridfs

I'm working on my first react project and I have an upload button through which the user can upload a set of files. I noticed that the file upload works perfectly for all file extensions, except for .json files. I'm not quite sure why that is, can anyone take a look at my addFile function? openUploadStream is the function given by mongoDB for GridFS storage of files.

```
const addFile = async (req, res) => {
  const { filename }  = req.body  
  const path = "cache\\" + filename //all files are stored in the cache folder

  const uploadStream = fs.createReadStream(path).
  pipe(bucket.openUploadStream(filename)) //store the file as the filename}

  res.status(200).json({id : uploadStream.id}) //return unique id of file in the db
  }
```

and in the frontend I call the API using axios

```
await axios.post('/api/filesRoute/fs', { filename : filename })
        .then((json) => {
             console.log('Success uploading', filename)
             raws.push(json.data.id)
        })
```

Comment: You can use the html File input, have it sent via a normal form submit ?

Comment: it doesnt look like you're uploading an actual file in the example you shared. Typically that's done with FormData and a file input or drag&drop event. In any case, I recommend using a library like react-uploady to upload files from the client. it takes care of a lot of edge cases that you probably dont want to handle youreself

Comment: @poeticGeek I have the file uploaded to a local folder named cache, and from there use its path to find the file and upload to GridFS. The above code is handling the transfer from the cache folder to GridFS. I get a proxy request error between my react and the server when I try to send a .json file to addFile. (ECONNREFUSED). So the issue occurs after the file has been downloaded locally.

Comment: perhaps you can share a closer code example to your actual code because its still unclear what you're doing and whats failing